# Kount + Laravel Integration: What is the Kount namespace/class?

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I am struggling to integrate Kount with my Laravel application. I have installed the PHP SDK using `composer require kount/kount-ris-php-sdk:*`, but when I go to use it in my checkout controller, I don't know what namespace/class name to use when importing it:

```
<?php

namespace App\Services;

use ??????????

class KountService
{
    public function inquiry(array $data)
    {
        // Minimal RIS inquiry example:
        try {
            $inquiry = new Kount_Ris_Request_Inquiry();
            ....
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

The files are in `./vendor/kount/kount-ris-php-sdk`, one of which (vendor\kount\kount-ris-php-sdk\src\Kount\Ris\Request\Inquiry.php) includes the class `Kount_Ris_Request_Inquiry`:

```
<?php
/**
 * Inquiry.php file containing Kount_Ris_Request_Inquiry class.
 */

/**
 * Perform an initial inquiry request (MODE 'Q' or 'P') to RIS.
 * Contains specific methods for setting various inquiry properties.
 *
 * @package Kount_Ris
 * @subpackage Request
 * @author Kount <custserv@kount.com>
 * @version $Id$
 * @copyright 2012 Kount, Inc. All Rights Reserved.
 */
class Kount_Ris_Request_Inquiry extends Kount_Ris_Request
{
    ...
}
```

so I tried `use Kount\Kount_Ris\Request` and `use Kount\Kount_Ris\Request as Kount_Ris_Request_Inquiry`, but neither of them worked.

Comment: `npm` is installing a Javascript package, nothing to do with PHP. Surely the documentation for this package must tell you how to use it.

Comment: And if you're looking at a source file, you can see exactly what the namespace is on the first line of the file???

Comment: @miken32 thank you for pointing that out, I meant the PHP SKD using composer require kount/kount-ris-php-sdk:*

Comment: @miken32 this source file doesn't show a namespace. I have edited my question to show the full top of the file

Comment: Then it isn’t namespaced

Comment: You can tell by package's `composer.json` mapping. Here, in this package you can see its autoload doesn't use `psr-4` nor `psr-0` mapping but rather plain files require/include. That can also tell you package doesn't follow latest industry standards.

Comment: @miken so does that mean it can't be used with Laravel or is there a different way to use it?

Comment: @Tpojka is there a way to require/include plain files in a Laravel controller?

Comment: What is the error you get when you try to invoke class `$inquiry = new Kount_Ris_Request_Inquiry();` without use statement?

Comment: @Tpojka `Class "App\Services\Kount_Ris_Request_Inquiry" not found`

Comment: Composer should still be able to manage it, good practice is to have `use Kount_Ris_Request_Inquiry;` in your controller but it shouldn’t be necessary. Try `composer dump-autoload ` to see if it helps.

Comment: Sorry. Try with root namespece `$inquiry = new \Kount_Ris_Request_Inquiry();` or @miken32 's advice.

Comment: @miken32 I swear I tried that, but it seems to be working now (or at least getting me past that point)